# I am trying to use JS/JQuery to automatically perform multiple find and replace actions on text in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m having issues with multiple replacements, I am wanting to replace the three words of a company name throughout the website with the company colours, I really don’t want to go through and manually add a span for each of the three words individually although I know this would work, is there anyway of doing this with code? BTW I’m a novice at JS/JQuery, etc.

I have had a go I can get one to work but when I try to do more than one only the last one works, it seems as though the last one cancels out the others.

I am happy enough with the CSS as this can easily be changed later.

Here is my code. - http://codepen.io/TechieBloke/pen/dMmNRB

```
var text = $('div').text().replace(/dummy/g, "<span class=artblack>dummy</span>");
$('div').html(text);

var text = $('div').text().replace(/Ipsum/g, "<span class='artgrey'>Ipsum</span>");
$('div').html(text);

var text = $('div').text().replace(/Lorem/g, "<span class='artred'>Lorem</span>");
$('div').html(text);
```

And here is the accompanying CSS

```
    .artblack {
  color: orange;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

.artgrey {
  color: blue;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}

.artred {
  color: red;
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: you need to use a loop e.g. `$('div').each(function(index){ // your code here});`

Comment: ok, I checked the codepen and what is happening is you are first inserting the result of first replace. Then you replace this html by the result of your second replace function and similarly for the third.

Comment: please note that you are fetching `text()` of the div, so it doesn't contain the `span` element you might have inserted in a previous step. It only gives you the text version, and so the result of previous replacement is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify the `html` each time, but then go back to `text` to use as source for the next change; just be more consistent and use `html()` instead:

```
$('div').html().replace()
```